# Mass replace while keeping numbers

Tags: regex

I am currently switching my structure as I changed it in depth and I need to go from something like this:

`database[NL()][211]`

To something like this :

`database_entry(211)`

The number inbetween is random (can go to 4 our 5 digits and so on) but I cannot replace what is around the number as it always replace the number with it.
I am using notepad++ to mass replace characters so it's a PCRE(2?) regex.

Here is what I've done so far (I am a regex beginner):

This one doesn't exclude numbers:
`(database\[NL\(\)\]\[)(\d+)(\])`

This one doesn't exclude numbers even though it's in a non capture group (because it's in the match):
`(database\[NL\(\)\]\[)(?:\d+)(\])`

I had also no success with ^ and ?! methods but I am probably doing it wrong simply.

Thanks you very much

Comment: What did you _Replace with_? (That's what matters.)

Comment: search: `(database)\[NL\(\)\]\[(\d+)\]` ; replace: `\1_entry(\2)` ?

Comment: Perfect! This did the trick! Thank you!
\1_entry\(\2\)